# Using Moodle APIs to change strings in activity plugin

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

In   my  Moodle  activity plugin I am trying   to  allow  an admin to  change  strings  from the settings  of the plugin.  The  strings  that  should be  changeable  are:  Teacher,  Class  and  Student .   These   are  used   throughout   my plugin. 
.
I  am  currently  attempting it  using  php constants  and that  is  working.

I  am   undecided  if this  is the the best  method  as  I am  converting  an  old  plugin  and  not  sure  what string  APIs  I could  use  for  Moodle  3.5.

Should  I just  proceed  with the  current  method as  it  is  working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the standard Moodle handling for language strings (i.e. store them in [plugin]/lang/en/[nameofplugin].php and retrieve them with get_string() ), then an admin can override them by visiting Site admin > Language > Customise language pack.

That would be the normal way to allow for strings to be modified by admins (which would also allow for the words to be correctly handled in contexts, e.g. having the correct gender for the displayed language, handling plurals, etc.)

Comment: But  those  strings  are  static.  How can  I make  the  strings in plugin]/lang/en/[nameofplugin].php   change  ?

Comment: You can override any language string by visiting Site admin > Language > Customise language pack

Comment: Yes  that  would  work  but  I  want  to  achieve  the  same  thing  from  within  my  plugin.   What  API  calls  would  I   need  to  achieve   this ?

Comment: The  fields  I want  to change  are  :  https://pasteboard.co/IrZbPhb.png

Comment: If your language strings are paramatised, then you could do it that way - e.g. $string['ident'] = 'Hello {$a}'; get_string('ident', 'myplugin', $nametoinsert).

Comment: Alternatively, you could try writing language files to [moodledata]/lang/en_local (off the top of my head that is where the language customisations go)

Comment: the   paramatised  version worked  for me :

$string['greeting'] = 'Dear {$a}';  -  saved  in  language  file

I could then  echo    where I need  it: 

echo get_string('greeting', 'mod_foo', CHANGE_CLASSNAME);  

CHANGE_CLASSNAME  being  my  php constant  defined in locallib.php  which  can  be  updated  from my  admin  form.

Comment: So  to  summaries this  line  does  what  I  want :

`echo get_string('greeting', 'mod_mymodule', get_config('module', 'changeclassname'));`